# how to add a partial view in the layout page in mvc 4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc. I want to add a partial view in my layout page.
for this i created an action method for partial view and using this action i craeted a partial view.
I want to add this partial view in all my other views...How can we do this

this is my action for partial view

```
public ActionResult _PartialIndex()
{
    IList<LawyerModel> lawyerList = new List<LawyerModel>();

    var query = (from lawyer in context.law_advocates
                    orderby lawyer.AdvocateID ascending
                    select lawyer).Take(35);

    var lawyerimg = query.ToList();

    foreach (var lawyerdata in lawyerimg)
    {
        lawyerList.Add(new LawyerModel()
        {
            AdvocateID = lawyerdata.AdvocateID,
            ImageID = lawyerdata.ImageID,
            ImagePath = "~/MemPhoto/" + lawyerdata.ImageID
        });
    }

    return PartialView(lawyerList);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add partial view in your layout page itself.

Please add like this

@Html.Partial(“partialViewName”)  // ‘partialViewName’ is the partial view name

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Partials/Widgets/_QuickSearch.vbhtml")
```

This works, try making sure the path to the partial is fully qualified.